# Docker-compose + MariaDB + 4GB SQL File = incredibly slow database import

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

We have the following MySQL node:

```
mysql:
    build: ./docker/builds/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=password
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/ps_de:/data
      - ./docker/builds/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql_shared
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 172.55.0.20
```

which basically justs pulls MariaDB with `FROM mariadb:latest`.

If we try to import huge SQL dumps into this DB it takes a huge amount of time to finish this task.

The dump itself is dumped with optimized settings and thus already "faster" then a normal dump.

On an HDD it takes up to 5 hours to import a 4GB dump and on a SSD it still takes up to 55 minutes. I've read about issues when importing such huge data to MySQL when using Docker.

Has anyone else this problem and how did you solved it?

Comment: did you find the solution yet? I am phasing same problem

Answer (score 0):

Data Imports in Docker are basically a standardized process.

The import speed is reliant on your SSD/HDD and the file size of the dump you're importing. Depending on the IO Speed of the HDD the import might take some time.

We've spend hours on hours on implementing a progress bar, but to be fair, its not worth the time since the speed won't increase with it as well.

What we've done to import a 50+GB Dump is generating a dump from the physical DB files (that are being stored inside MariaDB/MySQL directly) rather than importing a Dump. Downloading a 50GB package is much faster than importing a 50GB dump.

Its not the best approach since you cannot apply Dev-Settings here (entrypoint of Docker does) and likely you'll need an SRE/DevOps from your comp to provide the Dump itself, but its worth the try.